# Identify the tools behind this REST application?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am having to make use of some existing code. I cannot contact the previous developer. Part of it is a REST application. I can see how it works, but there is a lot of stuff that looks like code duplication. Or there is a tool of some kind which is taking some of the sources and creating articfacts and other sources from that, or it is creating templates, in which code was added. It looks a bit like Jersey but I have not used this in work, so I am not sure. I tried searching for the annotations, but that is not helpful. I may be missing the build files. It was in an eclipse project and I do not seem to have the .project directory.

This project has a lot of partial implementations that got set aside. I am having problems distringushing those from code that should work.

Looking for just "UserEmail", I see:

```
 src/com/gs/dao/user/UserEmailDao.java
 src/com/gs/dao/user/UserEmailDaoImpl.java
 src/com/gs/service/UserEmailService.java
 src/com/gs/service/UserEmailServiceImpl.java
```

This is not just 4 times the necessary code. Something is driving this structure. But what is it? Any suggestions?

I am seeing code like:

```
 @ApiController("1.0")
 public class UserEndpoint extends BaseEndpoint {

         Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserEndpoint.class);

         @Autowired
         public UserService userService;

         @Autowired
         public UserContactService userContactService;
 ....
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
 src/com/gs/cache
 src/com/gs/cache/local
 src/com/gs/cache/mem
 src/com/gs/servlet
 src/com/gs/constants
 src/com/gs/common
 src/com/gs/dao
 src/com/gs/dao/service
 src/com/gs/dao/service/attr
 src/com/gs/dao/user
 src/com/gs/dao/user/attr
 src/com/gs/dao/comm
 src/com/gs/dao/comm/attr
 src/com/gs/dao/vg
 src/com/gs/dao/vg/attr
 src/com/gs/dao/general
 src/com/gs/dao/general/attr
 src/com/gs/dao/exception
 src/com/gs/elasticsearch
 src/com/gs/service
 src/com/gs/service/utils
 src/com/gs/service/helper
 src/com/gs/graph
 src/com/gs/graph/gateway
 src/com/gs/threads
 src/com/gs/async
 src/com/gs/async/test
 src/com/gs/async/handler
 src/com/gs/async/impl
 src/com/gs/util
 src/com/gs/util/xss
 src/com/gs/nlp
 src/com/gs/exception
 src/com/gs/cassandra
 src/com/gs/cassandra/dao
 src/com/gs/search
 src/com/gs/search/service
 src/com/gs/rest
 src/com/gs/rest/common
 src/com/gs/rest/api
 src/com/gs/rest/api/test
```

What the heck is all this stuff? :-)

Comment: It's a Spring application with a service and DAO layer.

Comment: I'm not an expert but it looks sort of like some Spring code I've reviewed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probbaly not going to get one response that answers this. And you may get shut down for the question being too broad, but I will try. First off:

```
 src/com/gs/dao/user/UserEmailDao.java
 src/com/gs/dao/user/UserEmailDaoImpl.java
 src/com/gs/service/UserEmailService.java
 src/com/gs/service/UserEmailServiceImpl.java
```

That's a pretty common java pattern, You have an email service, and you split that into an interface and an implementation. You might consider it overkill (if the implementation never changes), but some of the tools being used might require interfaces.  Same thing with the UserEmailDao data access object. It's pretty normal for java developers to split everything into an interface and an implementation, though it drives people using dynamic languages crazy.

As for what's generating the REST app, you need to track down where the ApiController annotation is coming from. It looks like it might be wrapper  around a Spring MVC class. Post the import statement for that annotation, or just follow it your IDE.

Spring is definitely being used to wire the entire app together.

It looks like a pretty typical medium sized java application to me. From the directory structure, I doubt there is any code generation going on.

If there's  a pom.xml (maven file) in the application root, that'll tell you everything you need to know about the application.

Comment: I knew that was a risk (about it being too general), but there is a kind of question at which an automated search will fail. If you do not know the keyword, or have a word that is too general, google at al are just useless. I felt that this question was of that type, and so needed a human, and that is what so.com has....

Comment: I wish maven was being used. No such luck.

Comment: Well, this is a reasonable answer. There still seems to be way too much code duplicated for some of it not to be generated. But O well.